# How to increase background color of a node to input text

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, nodes, size, fill

Obviously I need a background color for the rightsided text. Code is from the Tantau manual, p.45. It's a riddle for me at the time. Something wrong with the node which keeps the text? 
For any answer I would be very appreciated. Sorry my pidgeon-english. Also I cannot post the code in a simple manner (manually 4 spaces for every line?) To see the result of the code on this side would be great.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%
[%node distance=5mm,
 text height=1.0em,
 text depth=.25em,
 every node/.style={%
    %rectangle,draw=black,
    inner sep=0pt},%
 %information text/.style={rounded corners,fill=red!10,inner sep=1em}
]
   %\draw[help lines, use as bounding box] (-7,-3) grid (7,3);

   \node (advbo)  {Adverbiale Bestimmung};
   %\node (po)                       {Pronomen};
   \node (po)    [left =.9mm of advbo]                   {Pronomen};
   \node (vo)    [left =.9mm of po]  {Verb};
   \node (advo)  [left =.9mm of vo]  {Adverb};
   %\node (advbo) [right=.5mm of po] {Adverbiale Bestimmung};

   \node (s) [below= of advo] {Schnell};
   \node (li) [below= of vo] {lief}; 
   \node (e1) [below= of po] {er};
   \node (h) [below= of advbo] {hin,};

   %\node (la) [below= of s] {langsam};
   \node (la) [below=.3mm of s] {langsam};
   \node (k) [below=.3mm of li] {kam};
   \node (e2) [below=.3mm of e1] {er};
   \node (z) [below=.3mm of h] {zur"uck.};

   \node (advu) [below= of la] {Adverb};
   \node (vu) [below= of k] {Verb};
   \node (pu) [below= of e2] {Pronomen};
   \node (advbu) [below= of z] {Adverbiale Bestimmung};

   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (advo)  to (s);
   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (advu)  to (la);

   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (vo)    to (li);
   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (vu)    to (k);

   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (po)    to (e1);
   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (pu)    to (e2);

   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (advbo) to (h);
   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (advbu) to (z);

   \draw[xshift=2.75cm,yshift=-.75cm]
      %node[right,text width=4cm,information text]
      node[right,text width=4cm,rounded corners,fill=red!10,inner sep=1em]
      {
         Parallelisierte Satzkonstruktionen ergeben, wenn man sie    untereinanderstellt, immer parallele Verbindungslinien.
      };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have found out that the code of the text node right is correct by putting it outside of the tikzpicture environment. But I am in this e., so is there a solution possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from `text height` and `text depth` defined in `tikzpicture` options. In this way, they apply to all nodes, and right hand text is a `node`, so its vertical size is defined by these values.

If you doesn't use `text height` and `text depth`, all other nodes won't be aligned, so it's not convenient to suppress them.

As I don't know how to `forget` previous values of `text height/depth` the best solution I can provide is apply these parameters to a particular `scope` where all little nodes are defined. And declare the right text node outside from it.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%
[%node distance=5mm,
% text height=1.0em,
% text depth=.25em,
 every node/.style={%
    %rectangle,draw=black,
    inner sep=0pt},%
 %information text/.style={rounded corners,fill=red!10,inner sep=1em}
]
   %\draw[help lines, use as bounding box] (-7,-3) grid (7,3);

\begin{scope}[text height=1.0em, text depth=.25em]
   \node (advbo)  {Adverbiale Bestimmung};
   %\node (po)                       {Pronomen};
   \node (po)    [left =.9mm of advbo]                   {Pronomen};
   \node (vo)    [left =.9mm of po]  {Verb};
   \node (advo)  [left =.9mm of vo]  {Adverb};
   %\node (advbo) [right=.5mm of po] {Adverbiale Bestimmung};

   \node (s) [below= of advo] {Schnell};
   \node (li) [below= of vo] {lief}; 
   \node (e1) [below= of po] {er};
   \node (h) [below= of advbo] {hin,};

   %\node (la) [below= of s] {langsam};
   \node (la) [below=.3mm of s] {langsam};
   \node (k) [below=.3mm of li] {kam};
   \node (e2) [below=.3mm of e1] {er};
   \node (z) [below=.3mm of h] {zur"uck.};

   \node (advu) [below= of la] {Adverb};
   \node (vu) [below= of k] {Verb};
   \node (pu) [below= of e2] {Pronomen};
   \node (advbu) [below= of z] {Adverbiale Bestimmung};
\end{scope}

   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (advo)  to (s);
   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (advu)  to (la);

   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (vo)    to (li);
   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (vu)    to (k);

   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (po)    to (e1);
   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (pu)    to (e2);

   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (advbo) to (h);
   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (advbu) to (z);

   \draw[xshift=2.75cm,yshift=-1.8cm]
      %node[right,text width=4cm,information text]
      node[right,text width=4cm, rounded corners,fill=red!10,inner sep=1em]
      {
         Parallelisierte Satzkonstruktionen ergeben, wenn man sie    untereinanderstellt, immer parallele Verbindungslinien.
      };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, great to receive so fast a solving answer. Too less practice of mine, but now I got a new feeling for "scope". Thank you!